# What's the definition of the "head" of a phrase?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

What's the definition of the “head” of a phrase?

I have come across two types of definitions:

- The first one uses circular reasoning (for an example, see the Wikipedia definition).  The head is defined by the category of a phrase and the category of a phrase is defined by the head (e.g. the noun is a head because the phrase is a noun phrase and the phrase is a noun phrase because the noun is a head).
- The second use vague and subjective terms.  A head is “essential”, “central” or “most important”.  But complements are essential.  And generative grammarians interpret what to most are noun phrases as “determiner phrases”, because they think determiners are most important.

Is there a better definition, or is this just one of those, make it into whatever you want?

Comment: Yes. You've put your finger on the problem. There are useful definitions, but mostly the concept of "head" is part of the set of epicycles that protect the [Projection Principle](https://www.google.com/search?q=Projection+Principle), which is a set of rules for marking tree structures in heiroglyphs. We get a lot of questions about that here.

Comment: The head determines the category and the category **is determined** by the head. That's active and passive rather than circular.

Comment: There is no problem or confusion. 'Head' is the most important element in a phrase. It can often stand alone without any dependents, as in "[Dogs] were barking", but most often it contains dependents, as in "[The big black dogs] were barking". Yes, the category of the head word determines the corresponding phrase category. In that example, "dog" is the head word and hence the bracketed element is a noun phrase.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thanks.  I've edited the question.

Comment: @BillJ Obligatorily transitive verbs and many prepositions can't "stand alone", yet they are heads.

Comment: @Bernie6 Examples?

Comment: @BillJ Off the top of my head, the verb "put".  "I put the dogs in the car."

Comment: Yes, "put" takes an obligatory complement, but it is still head of the VP "put the dogs in the car". Nothing odd about it. As I said, sometimes a head has no dependents, sometimes it does, some of which may be obligatory, as in your "put" example.

Comment: This belongs on [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com). It's not about the English language.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. English syntax is a main part of English grammar.  See the "help" section [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where you will find grammar as the second item under "questions on the following topics are welcomed here".

Comment: @Bernie6 This isn't about English syntax per se. Your question will get much better answers from people who actually care about the question on Linguistics. I upvoted your question, but it would be much, much better over there.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks.  I might try it over there.

Answer (score 1):

The head of a phrase determines two things: what sort of dependents can appear in that phrase, and what functions that phrase may take on in other phrases, clauses, etc.

For example, noun phrases may have as dependents determiners, and may function as subject in a clause and object in a verb or preposition phrase. That's not to say that all noun phrases have determiners, or that all function as subject or object; but simply that typical noun phrases can take determiners and can function as subject or object. For a full listing of dependents appearing in typical noun phrases, and functions fulfilled by typical noun phrases, one should consult one's favorite reference grammar. In so far, then, as any unit in question matches the typical noun phrase in its ability to take dependents and take on functions, it is said to be a noun phrase.

And so for each sort of phrase and its respective head.

---

As there has been some confusion as to the definition of a 'dependent' that is being used in the above explanation, I'll refer to the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar (Second Edition 2014).

> **dependent** (n. & adj.) (A linguistic unit) that is *subordinate to some
> other linguistic unit.
>
> **dependent element, phrase, clause**, etc.: any unit other than the *head within a *phrase, e.g. a *modifying phrase inside another phrase (*the **dead** rat*); a subordinate clause functioning as *complement of a verb (*I think **that it’s too late for coffee***), etc.

Comment: But dependency can be two way, so we are back to circularity.

Comment: Burton-Roberts, in chapter 2 (page 32) of Analysing Sentences, defines the head-complement relation as, and I quote, "a two-way (mutual) dependency".

Comment: @DW256: There are many varieties of "modern grammar". Just as there are of "modern cinema". Give a source and tests. Otherwise nobody knows what it means.

Comment: @JohnLawler Happy to oblige, though as far as the tests go, the asker will have to apply the contents of the answer.

Comment: @Bernie6 Are you sure that Burton-Roberts means "dependency" in the technical sense? My 80-year-old mother might depend (in the colloquial sense) on me for care, but when we talk about familial relationships, it is clear that she is the head and I am the dependent.

Answer (score 1):

*A dictionary of linguistics and phonetics* (6th Ed.) by David Crystal defines **head** as follows:

> A term used in the grammatical description of some types of phrase (endocentric phrases) to refer to **the central element which is distributionally equivalent to the phrase as a whole**

(Emphasis mine.)

A phrase may or may not have a central element which is distributionally equivalent to the phrase as a whole. So a phrase can be either endocentric or exocentric. And whether a phrase is endocentric or exocentric depends on the theory you adopt, and so does which element of an endocentric phrase is the head.

For example, traditionally, sentence S comprising NP and VP was considered exocentric because neither NP nor VP can be distributionally equivalent to S. But X-bar theory changed all that by analyzing S as an inflection phrase (IP), which is essentially a projection of VP (which in turn is a projection of the verb).

Comment: Right. Thanks. This is the distributional property that's been codified as the Projection Principle, like the circular orbits of the planets was codified by adding epicycles, until ellipses were finally recognized as canonically correct. As you say, not all constituents project.